# Upload multiple file using single sql query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using file upload control..in asp.net..storing files first in temp directory
and then after when user clicks on save I move files from temp to my desired location.
Problem is I have to used for loop and make 5 times trip to database for my insert query to insert 5 records.But I want to write single query for that.
I know that I can send my image name as well as image path comma seprated.but since i dont have enough knowledge of sql,I dont know how to split comma seprated files in sql and then using cursor insert them.So i request some one write me a sample query over here.so that i can proceed.

Comment: Did you google for `"SQL Server Split function"`?

Comment: Can you show the code you already have?

Comment: this is the code                                                 DataTable dtfileupload = new DataTable();
                            DataColumn dcID = new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)); 
                            dtfileupload.Columns.Add(dcID);
                            dtfileupload.Columns.Add("Imagename", typeof(string));
                            dtfileupload.Columns.Add("Imagepath", typeof(string));   In this datatable there will be 3 entires now i want to save this in sql in single query

Comment: Please refer to following links if it might help (links to understand usage of cursor)--- http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=162495

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204577/exporting-binary-file-data-images-from-sql-via-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can pass dataset as xml to stored procedure and in stored procedure you can insert multiple rows in one go  using openXML

C# code for passing dataset object as xml to stored procedure

```
         ...................................

    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // assume dataset has records(in table object)
    string xmlString = ds.GetXml();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your procedure name", "your Connection object");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@XmlString",xmlString);
             ...................................
```

stored procedure, bulk insert using openXML

```
      ...................................

  DECLARE @XMLDocPointer INT    
  EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocPointer OUTPUT, @XmlString    

   INSERT INTO Employee
   (Name, Email, PhoneNo)    
   SELECT Name,Email,PhoneNo   
   FROM OPENXML(@XMLDocPointer,'/ROOT/DATA',2)    
   WITH  (Name VARCHAR(50),-- '@Name',     
         Email VARCHAR(50),-- '@Email',     
         PhoneNo VARCHAR(50) --'@PhoneNo')     

   EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocPointer    
        ...................................
```

read this for complete example
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417181/Bulk-Insertion-of-Data-Using-Csharp-DataTable-and

===================================================================

if you looking for split string in sql
then below is the sql function that you need to create in sqlserver

```
create function f_split(@SourceSql varchar(8000),@StrSeprate varchar(10))
returns @temp 
table(a varchar(100))
begin    
 declare @i int    
 set @SourceSql=rtrim(ltrim(@SourceSql)) 
 set @i=charindex(@StrSeprate,@SourceSql)    
 while @i>=1    
 begin        
  insert @temp values(left(@SourceSql,@i-1))        
  set @SourceSql=substring(@SourceSql,@i+1,len(@SourceSql)-@i)        
  set @i=charindex(@StrSeprate,@SourceSql)    
 end    
 if @SourceSql<>'\'       
 insert @temp values(@SourceSql)    
 return 
end
go
```

and how to call

```
select * from dbo.f_split('1,2,3,4,5',',')
```

and then using cursor you can insert all

for split function, see this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4126a010-6885-4eb0-b79c-c798c90edb85

Comment: I have tried your code..bt nothing happen..my xml string is <NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Imagename>Chrysanthemum.jpg</Imagename>
    <Imagepath>/prop_images/temp/Chrysanthemum.jpg</Imagepath>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Imagename>Desert.jpg</Imagename>
    <Imagepath>/prop_images/temp/Desert.jpg</Imagepath>
  </Table1></NewDataSet>