# Export Images from SQL Server and name each image as a combination of keys in composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, export

I have a database in MS-SQL Server 2008 R2 with about 4000+ records. The schema of the table is as follows

```
TableName: ImageData

ColumnName Datatype
Key1        int 
Key2       varchar(50)
Key3       varchar(50)
Value       Image
PrimaryKey(Key1,Key2,Key3)
```

I want to export images from the table to disk as jpg such that output is key1+key2+key3.jpg

Any T-SQL script that will do the job?. I tried the scripts available with changes commands were executed properly but there were no output images. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code given on the following link would solve your purpose:

[How to export image field to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file)

Comment: I used this code. It gives "Command(s) executed successfully but now output images are stored on the disk.

Comment: What you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. I'm printing path within the loop for debugging but no folder is created and no images are stored on the disk.

Comment: Is the Path created on your system? If not please try by first creating the path on your system and then running the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If was only the path issue. I create a new path in C:/Images and all the images are extracted now.