# Does ADODB.Stream have a maximum file size it can handle?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005, and exporting image data types to files (From a Sharepoint database), using a script not too dissimilar to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file)

It works well, but for some reason with it fails on files that are more than ~45MB:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

So, I've had to add the argument `WHERE DATALENGTH(Content)/1024 <= 45000` so that it runs through the files it can without failing.

Does anyone know if ADODB.Stream has a maximum file size it can handle?

Comment: Are there other errors?

Comment: They are the only errors it replies with

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much into Sharepoint's nor SQL Server processes and stuff, however, I was looking for something like this regarding Classic ASPs (that's how I reached your question). In my case it seems like the Response.BinaryWrite method has a 20MB limitation and I had send the stream in several smaller parts.

Maybe there's the same thing here.
Check this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424068/how-to-avoid-sp-oacreate-limits)** and it's answers, I think it may have some clues for what you're looking.

Good luck!