# How to avoid sp_OACreate limits?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000); 
Declare @Url as Varchar(MAX);

set @Url = 'http://mysite.ru/cgi-bin/my_xml.cgi'

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT; 
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @Url, 'false' 
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send' 
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT 
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object

SELECT @ResponseText
```

XML length in url is 4210 and  `@ResponseText` return `NULL` , when I change length to 3970  `@ResponseText` return me data. Does sp_OACreate have limit 400 ? If yes if it possible to avoid ?

Comment: Why are you using ActiveX to read data from a site? It's far easier, faster, scaleable, safer to use SSIS for ETL jobs, which is what you are doing here. T-SQL *really* isn't the proper place to make calls to web services. If you absolutely must do so, at least write a UDF in .NET to do this. SSIS includes `XML` and `Web Service` tasks already

Comment: The best way to avoid the limits is to avoid sp_OA procedures like the plague. There are many better ways of doing thing like this in all versions of sql server after 2000.

Comment: @SeanLange can you give me example ?

Comment: This would be much better in a CLR procedure or an SSIS package. This looks like it came from 1998. I mean sp_OACreate hitting a cgi-bin is not something I have seen in a LONG time.

Comment: @SeanLange I had never use CLR procedure , can you give example how to take xml  from url using clr ?

Comment: You should google CLR. It is a procedure in sql server that is running .net code. It is extremely powerful but can also be a pain to setup correctly. If this was my system I would probably do this with SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

despite the subject of your post i think that the issue is likely with sp_OAMethod and not sp_OACreate itself.

also IMHO accessing the web from sql code should be avoided at all costs but this is just my opinion because i don't like the idea having a RDBMS 'surfing the web'. ^^

to circumvent the limitation of sp_OAMethod you can try to elaborate an answer present on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac224833-1ffa-4008-880c-ce8f4d442110/trying-to-obtain-xml-data-from-url-via-sql).

your code should become something like this:

```
Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000); 
Declare @Url as Varchar(MAX);

set @Url = 'http://mysite.ru/cgi-bin/my_xml.cgi'

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT; 
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @Url, 'false' 
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send' 
--Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT 

INSERT #temptable ( appropriatefield )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'YourPropertyName' 

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

the solution requires a temp table with appropriate structure and datatype to store the value produced by the remote page and this should allow you to get more than 4k of data.

Comment: `@Object,@Result,@Obj` are varchar(8000) type ? and what about 'YourPropertyName'  ? what should i write there for get xml for url ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1141571-392-1.aspx) on sqlservercentral.com, sp_OACreate is limited to 4000 characters.

A workaround is to split up the read into smaller "chunks" that are then concated together in SQL. Here is a code snippet from the above link, that might help you although it reads XML from file instead of through HTTP:

```
EXECUTE @hResult = sp_OACreate  ''Scripting.FileSystemObject'' , @objFileSystem OUT
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN 
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objFileSystem, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT 
    SET @ErrorFailPoint = ''Creating FSO''
    GOTO DestroyFSO 
    RETURN 
END     

SET @FileNameAndPath = @Path + ''\'' + @FileName

-- Read file
EXECUTE @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objFileSystem, ''OpenTextFile'', @objTextStream OUT, @FileNameAndPath, 1, false, 0--for reading, FormatASCII
IF @hResult <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objFileSystem, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT 
        SET @ErrorFailPoint = ''Opening Reponse File''
        GOTO Destroy 
        RETURN 
    END 

    SET @ResponseText = ''''

    WHILE @hResult = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE @hResult = sp_OAGetProperty @objTextStream, ''AtEndOfStream'', @YesOrNo OUTPUT
        IF @hResult <> 0 
        BEGIN 
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objTextStream, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT 
            SET @ErrorFailPoint = ''Checking AtEndOfStream''
            GOTO Destroy 
            RETURN 
        END     

        IF @YesOrNo <> 0
        BREAK

        EXECUTE @hResult = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, ''Read'', @Chunk OUTPUT, 4000
        IF @hResult <> 0 
        BEGIN 
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objTextStream, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT 
            SET @ErrorFailPoint = ''Reading Chunk''
            GOTO Destroy 
            RETURN 
        END     
        SET @ResponseText = @ResponseText + ISNULL(@Chunk, '''')
    END

    EXECUTE @hResult = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, ''Close''
    IF @hResult <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objTextStream, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT 
        SET @ErrorFailPoint = ''Closing Response File''
        GOTO Destroy 
        RETURN 
    END     

    -- Record response info
    SET @ResponseXml = CAST(@ResponseText AS XML)

Destroy: 
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @objTextStream

DestroyFSO:
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @objFileSystem
```

Comment: with nvarchar(max) also return NULL

Comment: How about using `varbinary(max)` ?

Comment: as I know sp_OACreate dont recognize (max) and with varbinary(max) I also have null in response

Comment: Hmm, could be that there is a limit to the number of bytes returned from `sp_OAMethod`. Could you please try one last thing: `Declare @ResponseText as xml`

Comment: with xml also null, maybe is there any encoding which will occupy 1 byte ? I can change utf-8 to any encoding

Comment: I have changed my answer. Take a look at [this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1141571-392-1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to overcome the limitation.  I use it for a RESTful api communication.  I can receive varchar(max) but am still limited on the amount of data I can send.  This might get you where you need to be.  The top 5 variables are the arguments I use for the sproc.

```
    Declare @url as varchar(1024)
    Declare @connection_type as varchar(6)='GET' --POST, PUT, GET DELETE
    Declare @post_string as varchar(max)=null
    Declare @response_text as Varchar(max)
    Declare @content_type varchar(254)='application/json'

    Declare @oa_object as Int;
    Declare @err_code as Int
    Declare @result_table Table (xml_result varchar(max))

    Select @post_string=dbo.fn_regex_replace('([ ]{2,10})|\r|\n', @post_string,'') --remove carriage returns and multiple spaces

    Exec @err_code=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0', @oa_object OUT;
    If @err_code<>0
        Set @response_text=dbo.fn_oa_error_message(@oa_object)
    Else
    Begin
        Exec @err_code=sp_OAMethod @oa_object, 'open', NULL, @connection_type, @url,'false','d0b1a0aaed2a529356471de4fe99cae2','8e7aa1a91fa68d06cd027914d3aa1140'
        If @err_code<>0
            Set @response_text='Open '+dbo.fn_oa_error_message(@oa_object)
        Else
        Begin
            Exec @err_code=sp_OAMethod @oa_object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)'
            If @err_code<>0
                Set @response_text='setRequestHeader:User-Agent '+dbo.fn_oa_error_message(@oa_object)
            Else
            Begin
                Exec @err_code=sp_OAMethod @oa_object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', @content_type
                If @err_code<>0
                    Set @response_text='setRequestHeader:Content-Type '+dbo.fn_oa_error_message(@oa_object)
                Else
                Begin
                    Exec @err_code=sp_OAMethod @oa_object, 'send', Null, @post_string
                    If @err_code<>0
                        Set @response_text='Send '+dbo.fn_oa_error_message(@oa_object)
                    Else
                    Begin
                        Set @response_text=null--make sure we don't return garbage
                        INSERT @result_table (xml_result)
                        Exec @err_code = sp_OAGetProperty @oa_object, 'responseText' 
                        If @err_code<>0
                            Set @response_text='responseText '+dbo.fn_oa_error_message(@oa_object)
                        Else
                            SELECT @response_text=xml_result FROM @result_table
                    End
                End
            End
        End
    End
    Exec sp_OADestroy @oa_object
```

Although you don't need it, the error handler is below.  It helps with troubleshooting.

```
CREATE FUNCTION
    dbo.n_oa_error_message(@oa_object int)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @source varchar(255)
    Declare @description varchar(255)   
    exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @oa_object, @source OUT, @description OUT        
    return 'Error: '+IsNull(@description,'no description')
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following query to solve this issue. The problem is probably not sp_OACreate or sp_OAMethod, but the way to return the @ResponseText. Inserting the data into a table variable instead of using "@ResponseText OUTPUT" is the key. Note that I changed the @Response to VARCHAR(MAX).

```
DECLARE @TABLEVAR TABLE (responseXml VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(200) 
SELECT @URL = 'http://mysite/php-start/callxml.php'

DECLARE @Response NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Xml XML
DECLARE @Obj INT 
DECLARE @Result INT

EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, SEND, NULL, ''

INSERT INTO @TABLEVAR
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj

SELECT @Response = responseXml FROM @TABLEVAR
SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, @Response, 2)

DECLARE @handle INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @Xml 

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/data/record', 2)  
    WITH [dbo].[tblDialogTechTemp]

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

> My query suddenly returned null without changing anything. After changing `'MSXML2.XMLHttp'` to `'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP'`, it started to work again. To know more about the difference between these two, see this [article](https://blog.srpcs.com/picking-the-correct-xmlhttp-object/) and Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762278(v=vs.85)).

Comment: If you use this in a SQL Server Agent job, remember to [SET TEXTSIZE -1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-textsize-transact-sql). Another way to get the job done is to use SSIS package to import plain csv file returned by the web api.