# Calling API From SQL Server - Response Size Issue

Tags: sql-server, api, get, response, limit

I am calling an (GET) API from SQL Server and storing the results in JSON. My running code is as follow:

```
DECLARE @Object AS Int;
DECLARE @hr INT
DECLARE @json AS TABLE(Json_Table nvarchar(max))
declare @username varchar(50), @password varchar(50), @encoded_base64 varchar(max), @auth varchar(max)
declare @source varbinary(max)

set @username = 'demousername'
set @password = 'demopassword'
SET @source = CONVERT(varbinary(max), @username + ':' + @password)
SET @encoded_base64 = CAST(N'' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')
SET @auth = 'Basic ' + @encoded_base64

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://demourl',
                 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @auth;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
select * from @json
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json), N'$.data')
WITH (   
      [Column1] nvarchar(max) N'$.column1.id'
)
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

The issue is that my API is returning a good amount of data (around 4 MB while storing the results in a file on disk manually) and SQL Server is presenting me with the following error:

```
Json_Table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Response size 1164KB has exceeded maximum supported size 1024KB. However, the output is still available to subsequent steps in the workflow.
```

However, my code is running fine without any issues if I have smaller data.

Please help me to address this error and move on.
Thanks in advance.

**P.S** I need to use the above mentioned methodology (i.e. using SQL to call my API) as a must so using any other tool like VS, SSIS etc. won't be helpful.

Comment: Just don't... Those old OA procedures are there for compatibility for old databases; like *really* old (SQL Server 2000) databases. Ideally to consume APIs really you should be using a process to *push* the data to SQL Server. Otherwise if you "must" do it in the SQL layer, then create your own CLR objects to do it. Don't rely on those objects that haven't seen any updates in the best part of 2 decades. The internet has moved on since then.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your prompt response but is there any solution to my problem within the boundaries I mentioned?

Comment: As I said, just don't use those procedures. It's not 2001 any more.

Comment: @Larnu then as suggested by you earlier, could you please provide me with examples of one or some so that I can follow the same path?

Comment: That is a *very* broad topic, and you haven't even stated what path you want to go down. Your favourite search engine will be your friend here.

Comment: @Larnu how about using an already available CLR?

Comment: You could search for one that might fit your needs, sure.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @Larnu answer: you will need either an external application (written in your choice of language e.g. C#, VB.NET to name few) OR you will need to write a [CLR stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/clr-stored-procedures) which is essentially a stored procedure written in a .NET language and deployed to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Alex and Larnu.
Anyone else could comment on the issue I stated initially?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid sp\_OACreate limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424068/how-to-avoid-sp-oacreate-limits)

Comment: Unfortunately, No @Alex.