# Verify data integrity for varbinary column

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, sql-server-2012

I am inserting a `.jpg` into a `varbinary(max)` column in SQL Server 2012 using the following command:

```
INSERT INTO Employees 
VALUES(5, (SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\4.jpg',SINGLE_BLOB) AS image))
```

It inserts a record in the table.

Then I used the following command to restore the file from db to file system.

```
BCP "SELECT pic FROM Employees where id=5" queryout "C:\51.jpg" -N -T
```

When I try to view the downloaded file using image viewer, I get an error

> File is damaged.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: [How to export image field to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file)

The short version without the cursor looks like this:

```
DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY(max)
DECLARE @FullPathToOutputFile NVARCHAR(2048);

SELECT @ImageData = pic FROM Employees WHERE id=5
SET @FullPathToOutputFile = 'C:\51.jpg'


DECLARE @ObjectToken INT
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FullPathToOutputFile, 2;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close';
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken;
```

Before you can do that you have execute this only once in your database:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

All credits belong to @mathijsuitmegen :) thanks for this working solution